# How do you be sarcastic in Japanese?

Tags: meaning, nuances

Especially in text, is there a clue in Japanese as to whether someone is being sarcastic, or is it as ambiguous as it is in English? And how do you form a sentence so as to make it obviously sarcastic?

Thank you very much.

Comment: this question is incredibly broad in scope.

Comment: I don't think I could even answer this question if it was asking about English. Could you perhaps reformulate it to be more specific?

Comment: You do not be sarcastic in Japanese.

Unless you like being met with lots of blank stares.

Comment: @Dave This related question seems to suggest otherwise: [Will verbal irony and sarcasm be understood and/or appreciated?](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/4154/will-verbal-irony-and-sarcasm-be-understood-and-or-appreciated)

Comment: くせに might be close to applicable here

Comment: Oh thanks for linking that question, Darius. I was curious because Japanese usually can convey something English cannot. I suppose I was asking what that guy was. Thanks.

Comment: Sarcasm, and irony, is done *all the time* in Japan. Let's dismiss the myth that Japanese are so culturally rigid and uniform that they are incapable of communication forms that any other culture can do. Japanese people can convey and receive any message that any other human can do, there are merely details about how. (Also: voted to close just because this question [has been answered](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/4154/will-verbal-irony-and-sarcasm-be-understood-and-or-appreciated).)