# Help with the meaning of 大絶賛 in this sentence

Tags: grammar, meaning, puns

> というわけで、俺は実家で只今大絶賛ひとり暮らし中である。

From what I can tell, the speaker is saying that for reasons mentioned he is living alone at home, but I don't see how 大絶賛 (which means very high praise) affects the meaning of the sentence. The meaning "high praise" seems to not fit in at all with the rest of the sentence or context. The word can be used in either noun form or suru-verb form, so its usage and placement has left me baffled. Is there perhaps some omission or something in play?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a joke played on the common marketing phrase "絶賛〜中". The most common of them is "絶賛発売中" which means it's being sold and getting very high praise.

<strike>Basically it's sarcasm.</strike>

**EDIT:**

I shouldn't have said sarcasm. It's more like just a word play with a bit of self deprecation. In particular, the speaker isn't trying to convey how bad the situation is received by saying "it's getting high praise". Pure sarcasm, especially those done subtly is really uncommon in Japanese.

Comment: Nice. And people say Japanese don't have a sense of sarcasm. ([They're wrong, of course](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/4159/119).)

Comment: Thanks, I thought it had to be something along those lines, given the almost completely negative context. I had heard about the lack of sarcasm in Japanese but I guess that wasn't true.

Comment: @EISigh: It's not *really* sarcasm as it is practices in the west though. It's more like a word play with a bit of self depreciation rather than stating the opposite. I do think real sarcasm is not part of daily communication in Japan.

Comment: +1 for the edit.  For it to be labeled as sarcasm, it would require a specific context.  Without further context, it would only be reasonable to say that the author said it just to make the readers laugh.