# Indicating a lack of surprise

Tags: expressions, phrase-requests

How do you indicate a lack of surprise at something? For example, in response to someone noting that Cyprus had given 12 points to Greece at the Eurovision Song Contest.

I tried using "本当に?" sarcastically, but I don't know how well it works.

Comment: The word "sarcastically" reminds me of this question: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/24057/7810

Answer (score 5):

- やっぱり
- 予想【よそう】通【どお】り
- 案【あん】の定【じょう】
- ほらね！
- お約束【やくそく】

And [many others](http://thesaurus.weblio.jp/content/%E6%A1%88%E3%81%AE%E5%AE%9A).

I don't know how to use 本当に sarcastically.